# How to loop through this kinda javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, datatables

I am returning data to my `DataTables` table but I am not able to loop through the below array:

```
["BREAKFAST (Vegetables)", "LUNCH-DINNER (Vegetables)"]
```

I tried the below code but it just prints the first item

```
{data: null,
    render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
        var categoriesNamesList = '';
        //loop through all the row details to build output string
        for (var item in row.categories_names) {
            var r = row.categories_names[item];
            //Check if r is NULL or Empty then skip
            if(r){
                categoriesNamesList = '<ul><li>'+ r + '</li></ul>';
            }
        }
        return categoriesNamesList;

    }
}
```

Comment: `categoriesNamesList = '<ul><li>'+ r + '</li></ul>';` - this is overwriting the variable each time. Do you mean to concatenate the strings with `+=`?

Comment: @RobinZigmond yes that was the issue! I was missing the concatenation array. My new code is `categoriesNamesList = categoriesNamesList + '<ul><li>'+ r + '</li></ul>';` and now it's printing all records. Thanks a million mate!

Answer (score 0):

Move the placement of the return inside the loop. Based on the code you have I could almost bet that you are getting only the last item.

```
render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
        var categoriesNamesList = '';
        //loop through all the row details to build output string
        for (var item in row.categories_names) {
            var r = row.categories_names[item];
            //Check if r is NULL or Empty then skip
            if(r){
                categoriesNamesList = '<ul><li>'+ r + '</li></ul>';
                return categoriesNamesList;
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could actually use a `.map(...)` on the array (assuming `row.categories_names`) in the following manner:

```
render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
    return row.categories_names.map(function(item) {
        return '<ul><li>'+item+'</li></ul>';
    });
}
```

It could be simpler. Let me know if it works.